# Winform application not updating when minimized

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows form application that seems to pause draw functions when it is minimized. I need to know whether this just some draw function quirk, or if it extends to all code running. In either case, is there a workaround to this issue?

Comment: Does this have something to do with getting the Aero Peek thumbnail to update while the window is minimized? If so, there is a separate API for that.

Answer (score 2):

If it's minimized, there's nothing visible to paint, and so there's no need for `WM_PAINT` messages to be sent or processed. Nothing else should be affected, unless you've done something wrong in your code to cause it to be.

See also [C# Windows Form Application update when minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1809820/62576) for some related information.

Comment: Is there a way to make it paint regardless? I know that it's a terrible design choice, but I'm curious.

Comment: I think that's answered in the link I posted, isn't it? (You can call `Update`.) But what would the point be? There's nothing visual to do with a minimized window; if you're doing something other than painting, you're doing it in the wrong place.